# Xcode Obj-C linking errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, mach-o

I am building a library for iOS, using an existing 3rd-party SDK. Got the code to compile and the library is generated. However, when linking against the resulting/my library, Xcode reports two missing symbols. I checked my library with nm(1) and indeed the symbols are both marked unresolved as below:

```
U _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyController
U _OBJC_CLASS_$_MySdk
```

The funny part is that the same symbols are defined in the SDK framework [library], or so I think. Please see nm & grep output below:

```
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_MySdk
0000000000008d10 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_MySdk
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_VKSdk
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_MySdk
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_MySdk

                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyViewController
000000000000ab88 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyViewController
```

Both of those classes (MySdk and MyViewController) are defined in the SDK framework and utilized through their CLASS methods. Don't know whether this is relevant.

Where should I look next?

Thank you

Comment: Project>Build phases>Compile sources, you see list of all files, look for MyViewController....it should not be highlighted in red.

Comment: Are you referring to target configurations? The two classes in question, are in the framework. How could Xcode highlighted these classes in the list of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to manually add my framework to the xcconfig file. Now, the code is compiled OK.